# changing the value of checkbox in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

The checked value from my checkbox is being saved as 0 in my database, I want it to save the checkbox value instead of 0.

```
<?php
$options = array(food => 'rice', 'beans', 'chips');
echo $form->input('food', array('multiple' => 'checkbox', 'options' => $options));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the keys of your array like:

```
    array('rice' => 'rice', 'beans' =>'beans', 'chips' =>'chips')
```

That could be like this

```
$options = [
    'rice' => 'Rice',
    'beans' => 'Beans',
    'chips' => 'Chips'
];
echo $this->Form->select('food', $options, [
    'multiple' => 'checkbox'
]);
```

For more info refer to this URL: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#options-for-select-checkbox-and-radio-controls